Не могу подключить aiogram_i18n, выдает ошибку TypeError: ...expandable_blockquote
Решаюсь в файле __main__.py в папке app добавить этот миддлварь:
...
from aiogram_i18n import I18nMiddleware
from aiogram_i18n.cores import FluentRuntimeCore
...

async def main() -> None:
    await setup_logging()

    bot = Bot(
        token=settings.BOT_TOKEN,
        default=DefaultBotProperties(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML),
    )
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=RedisStorage(redis=redis_storage()))

    dp.include_routers(user.router, admin.router, group.router, errors.router)
    ...
    dp.update.middleware(UoWMiddleWare(session_factory=session_factory()))

    mw = I18nMiddleware(
        core=FluentRuntimeCore(
            path="locales/{locale}",
        ),
    )

    mw.setup(dispatcher=dp)

    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

А в хендлере(роутеры, которые я подключил внизу) приватного чата, у меня так:
from typing import Any

from aiogram import Router, F
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import Command, CommandStart
from aiogram.methods import TelegramMethod
from aiogram_i18n import I18nContext

from app.repositories import UserRepository
from app.models import Users
from app.filters import AdminFilter, ChatTypeFilter

router = Router()
router.message.filter(ChatTypeFilter(chat_type=["private"]))


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(
    message: Message, user: Users, user_service: UserRepository, i18n: I18nContext,
) -> TelegramMethod[Any]:

    await message.answer(text=i18n.messages.start(name=user.mention))

Во fluent файлах написано вот так: messages-start = "Hello { $name }!"
Вот как это расположено:
├── app
│   └── __main__.py
|   ...
│
└── locales
    │
    ├── ru
    │   └── messages.ftl
    │
    └── en
        └── messages.ftl

и после всего этого я запускаю бота через команду python -m app и вылетает ошибка:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/home/.../job/telegram_bot/app/__main__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from aiogram_i18n.cores import FluentRuntimeCore
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1229, in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/.../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/telegram-bot-a3iI3O79-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram_i18n/cores/__init__.py", line 29, in __getattr__
    return cast(BaseCore[Any], getattr(import_module(__cores__[name], "aiogram_i18n.cores"), name))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/.../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/telegram-bot-a3iI3O79-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram_i18n/cores/fluent_runtime_core.py", line 5, in <module>
    from aiogram_i18n.utils.text_decorator import td
  File "/home/.../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/telegram-bot-a3iI3O79-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram_i18n/utils/text_decorator.py", line 124, in <module>
    td = TextDecoration()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/.../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/telegram-bot-a3iI3O79-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/aiogram_i18n/utils/text_decorator.py", line 55, in __init__
    None: Null(),
          ^^^^^^
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Null with abstract method expandable_blockquote

Я пробовал даже просто установить default locale и другое(написал еще один миддлварь у которого методы get_locale, set_locale, там просто работал еще с бд, где сохранял language code пользователя), но ничего не изменилось
Мне иногда кажется что проблема с версией, у меня все версии зависимостей последней версии, aiogram, aiogram_i18n, fluent - все из них тоже последней версии:
 1. aiogram-i18n = {extras = ["compiler"], version = "^1.3.4"}
 2. aiogram = "^3.7.0"
 3. fluent-compiler   1.1
 4. fluent-syntax     0.19.0
 5. babel             2.15.0



Прошу прощения, я исправил, переустановив aiogram_i18n, в зависимостях poetry теперь стоит:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
aiogram = "^3.7.0"
asyncpg = "^0.29.0"
sqlalchemy = "^2.0.30"
redis = "^5.0.4"
pydantic-settings = "^2.2.1"
alembic = "^1.13.1"
fluent-runtime = "^0.4.0"
fluent-compiler = "^1.1"
aiogram-i18n = "^1.4"

Все заработало

похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

нет, прошу прощения, это и есть ответ, я изменил
